# How is DME station ident coded in ARINC 429?

Tags: arinc-429, dme

I understand that labels 242,244, 246, 247 are set for DME Station Id or DME Station Ident. they are marked as discrete. How should I convert the station code from alphabet to these 'discretes'? The station codes are something like AGG.

Answer (score 1):

Labels 246 and 247 describe up to 4 7-bit ASCII characters.

- 1th char: Bits 11-17 of 246
- 2th char: Bits 19-25 of 246
- 3th char: Bits 11-17 of 247
- 4th char: Bits 19-25 of 247

For `AGG`, in ASCII we get `0x41`, `0x47`, `0x47`, then:

- Label 246 = 0x11D04A6
- Label 247 = 0x11CA7

SSM encoding is the same as regular discrete labels.

I am not familiar with labels 242/244.